# read-from-string working in NetLogoWeb?

Tags: netlogo

Is there any alternative to read-from-string that works in NetLogoWeb? I need to a string from an input field. The string contains some number of integers and should be converted to a list. Within NetLogo, I use this code:

```
to-report get-demand
  report reverse sort read-from-string ( word "[" the-field-name "]")
end
```

However, it seems that read-from-string is not implemented yet in NetLogoWeb. Any way around?

Many thanks and best wishes,
Michal

P.S. Many thanks for developping NetLogoWeb. I really missed NetLogo plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
to-report string-to-numbers [s]
  if empty? s [ report [] ]
  if first s = " " [ report string-to-numbers butfirst s ]
  let pos position " " s
  ifelse not is-number? pos
    [ report (list string-to-number s) ]
    [ report fput string-to-number substring s 0 pos
                  string-to-numbers substring s (pos + 1) length s ]
end

to-report string-to-number [s]
  report reduce [10 * ?1 + ?2]
                map [position ? "0123456789"]
                    explode s
end

to-report explode [s]
  report map [item ? s] n-values (length s) [?]
end
```

Sample run:

```
observer> show string-to-numbers "12 345 67"
observer: [12 345 67]
```

I verified that this works in both desktop NetLogo and NetLogo Web.

Comment: Very clever but slightly less resilient. In my version, bad characters (e.g. letters) are ignored. In your version, they throw and error. However, I think this could be handled. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we haven't yet added support for `read-from-string` to NetLogo Web.  It probably won't be there in the near future, either.

Is the code supplied here the real code that's giving you problems?  I assume that it isn't, but, if it is, you can just do this for the same effect:

`to-report get-demand
  report reverse sort (list the-field-name)
end`

(That is, if `the-field-name` is what it sounds like, which would be a string containing only the name of some "field".)

I assume that your real case is more complex.  I might be able to offer a better workaround if I saw the true code.  Are you sure that you can't solve your problem with [tasks](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#tasks)?

Comment: In fact, it is the real code. And your solution does not work. Since the input must be a string (many numbers are entered, separated by spaces), the result of your code is a list with one string: [" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11"]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answer (that the command will not be implemented soon), it seems the only solution is to implement a simple parser, i.e. something like this (works for integers separated by spaces):

```
to-report string-to-list [ s ]
let l []
let ss ""
let n 0
let mode "out"
repeat length s [
  set ss first s
  set s but-first s
  if ( ( ss = " ") and ( mode = "in" ) ) [
    set mode "out"
    set l lput n l
    set n 0
  ]
  if ( member? ss "0123456789") [ 
    set mode "in"
    set n ( n * 10 ) + ( position ss "0123456789" )
  ]
]
if ( mode = "in" ) [ set l lput n l ]
report l
end
```

The reporter gets a string s and returns a list of integers.

Or is there any simpler way to implement it?

Comment: See my answer for alternate approach using `map` and `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to have an up-to-date answer here, [as of October 2017](http://staging.netlogoweb.org/whats-new), NetLogo Web does support `read-from-string`.  A case like `read-from-string (word "[" the-field-name "]")` should work just as in desktop and report the list value.